# How to handle 100 000 together api request in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-athena

i am facing some serious problem here. i am working on aws lambda with node js. my task is to insert all the athena table data into mailchimp if user already exist i am updating that user if not i am inserting the user into mailchimp,but in athena db we have 100k data. 100k rows, each row is one persons data.
the problem is here its not inserting all the user data into the mailchimp instead of its inserting some of the data but not the all i dont know why.

```
 const md5 = require("md5");
    var Mailchimp = require("mailchimp-api-v3");
    var mailchimp = new Mailchimp("b689f064af1165f83d7309795b64095c-us14");
    require("dotenv").config();
    const _ = require("lodash");
    const athena = require("../src/DB/athena");
    const rds = require("../src/DB/rds");
    
    exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
      let list_id = "578a0790b0";
      try {
        const athena_Data = await athena();
        const rds_Data = await rds();
    
        let AudienceData = await Promise.all(
          athena_Data.Items.map(async (members) => {
            if (members.contact_email !== undefined) {
              let data1 = await rds_Data.rows.map((data) => {
                let merge_tags = data.merge_tag;
                let obj = { name: data.athena_column, value: merge_tags };
                return obj;
              });
              var object = data1.reduce(
                (obj, item) => Object.assign(obj, { [item.name]: item.value }),
                {}
              );
              let output = {};
              _.forIn(object, (value1, key1) => {
                _.forIn(members, (value, key) => {
                  if (key1 === key) {
                    return (output[value1] = value);
                  }
                });
              });
              let email_hash = md5(members.contact_email);
              await mailchimp
                .get(`/lists/${list_id}/members/${email_hash}`)
                .then(async (result) => {
                  await mailchimp
                    .put(`/lists/${list_id}/members/${email_hash}`, {
                      email_address: members.contact_email,
                      email_type: "text",
                      status: "subscribed",
                      merge_fields: {
                        ...output,
                      },
                      interests: {},
                      language: "",
                      vip: false,
                      location: {
                        latitude: 0,
                        longitude: 0,
                      },
                      marketing_permissions: [],
                      ip_signup: "",
                      timestamp_signup: "",
                      ip_opt: "",
                      timestamp_opt: "",
                      tags: [],
                    })
                    .then((response) => {
                      console.log("updated successfully", response);
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                      console.log("something went wrong with update", err);
                    });
                })
                .catch(async (err) => {
                  await mailchimp
                    .post(`/lists/${list_id}/members`, {
                      email_address: members.contact_email,
                      email_type: "text",
                      status: "subscribed",
                      merge_fields: {
                        ...output,
                      },
                      interests: {},
                      language: "",
                      vip: false,
                      location: {
                        latitude: 0,
                        longitude: 0,
                      },
                      marketing_permissions: [],
                      ip_signup: "",
                      timestamp_signup: "",
                      ip_opt: "",
                      timestamp_opt: "",
                      tags: [],
                    })
                    .then((res) => {
                      console.log("inserted successfully", res);
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                      console.log("something went wrong with post", err);
                    });
                });
            } else {
              console.log("email does not exist");
            }
          })
        );
        callback(null, "success");
      } catch (e) {
        callback(e, null);
      }
    };

example:
  For refrences or example
        let object={
          address_1: 'MERGE38',
          birth_date: 'MERGE37',
          address_2: 'MERGE39',
          address_3: 'MERGE40',
          zip: 'MERGE42',
          state: 'MERGE41',
          first_name: 'MERGE30',
          last_name: 'MERGE31',
          status: 'MERGE35',
          city: 'MERGE36',
          person_id: 'MERGE32',
          age: 'MERGE33'
        }
        let members={
          person_id: 170207,
          first_name: 'Vladislav1',
          last_name: 'Sheykhet',
          address_1: '5188 Foggy Prairie Manor',
          city: 'Coats',
          state: 'VA',
          zip: '244449454.0',
          sex: 'M',
          contact_phone: '(212) 213-4808',
          contact_email: 'vladislav@gmail.com',
          smoker_status: 'N'
        }
        let output={
          MERGE38: '5188 Foggy Prairie Manor',
          MERGE42: '244449454.0',
          MERGE41: 'VA',
          MERGE30: 'Vladislav1',
          MERGE31: 'Sheykhet',
          MERGE36: 'Coats',
          MERGE32: 170207
        }
```

Comment: @mongeshmadhavan no lambda take 15min last ,i gave 5 mins time,but its giving success msg but its not inserting all the records ,so that is my problem

Comment: People living outside India won't have any idea what a "lakh" (or "lac") is, so please don't use Indian words here.

Comment: Does mail chimp impose any kind of API rate limit or throttling? Maybe check that?

Comment: @JamesZ both are correct "lac" is an english variant for lakh but both are used

Comment: @SagarP Yes, they are used, but in **India**. Rest of the world does not use anything like lakh or lac.

Comment: @NickyTheWrench The marketing Api sets a limit of 10 simultaneously processing requests per user.Additional requests over the limit receive a 429 response[